# In Matlab, how to convert a polygon in matrix data to a vector of complex number?

Tags: matlab-figure

I'm trying to convert a polygon in a bitmap image (matrix) to a vector of complex numbers.I trying to make a small code to do that job but it doesn't work. I wonder if someone has met this problem, could you please help me out here? Thanks in advance!
Nhat,

Comment: Could you please specify things like the desired output (what should be the meaning of the complex numbers)? Do you want the real\imaginary parts to be the `(x,y)` coordinates of the vertices (or what...)? Also, if you could upload the source image to some website (such as imgur, imageshack, etc.) and link it in your question - this may be helpful. Please also take a look at [these](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/elementary-polynomials.html) built-in functions available in MATLAB to work with polygons.   ...and welcome to stackoverflow :)